Selenium in Docker Python
I'm trying to start Selenium in docker container and test the Chrome instance on my host.
Here is my Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN pip3 install selenium
RUN mkdir app 
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./  /app/

CMD ["bash"]

And here is my simple Python script. Python script works on my mac correctly.
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

sleep(5)

browser.close()

I'm getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 89, in driver_location
args = [str(self.get_binary()), "--browser", browser]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 63, in get_binary
raise WebDriverException(f"Unsupported platform/architecture combination: {sys.platform}/{arch}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsupported platform/architecture combination: linux/aarch64

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 4, in 
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in init
super().init(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 49, in init
self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

Please advise what am I missing
